# TLA+ model checker fails to generate states

Tags: proof, tla+

I've been following this course https://learntla.com/introduction/example/ however I'm having difficulty running the model. It does not generates any states at all

Version TLA+ = 1.8

```
------------------------------ MODULE Example ------------------------------


=============================================================================
\* Modification History
\* Last modified Fri Sep 03 17:43:29 IST 2021 by faish
\* Created Fri Sep 03 17:15:54 IST 2021 by faish

EXTENDS Naturals, TLC
(* --algorithm transfer
variables alice_account = 10, bob_account = 10, money \in 1..20

begin
A: alice_account := alice_account - money;
B: bob_account := bob_account + money;
C: assert alice_account >= 0;

end algorithm*)
\* BEGIN TRANSLATION (chksum(pcal) = "4f516040" /\ chksum(tla) = "66759d32")
VARIABLES alice_account, bob_account, money, pc

vars == << alice_account, bob_account, money, pc >>

Init == (* Global variables *)
        /\ alice_account = 10
        /\ bob_account = 10
        /\ money \in 1..20
        /\ pc = "A"

A == /\ pc = "A"
     /\ alice_account' = alice_account - money
     /\ pc' = "B"
     /\ UNCHANGED << bob_account, money >>

B == /\ pc = "B"
     /\ bob_account' = bob_account + money
     /\ pc' = "C"
     /\ UNCHANGED << alice_account, money >>

C == /\ pc = "C"
     /\ Assert(alice_account >= 0, 
               "Failure of assertion at line 16, column 4.")
     /\ pc' = "Done"
     /\ UNCHANGED << alice_account, bob_account, money >>

(* Allow infinite stuttering to prevent deadlock on termination. *)
Terminating == pc = "Done" /\ UNCHANGED vars

Next == A \/ B \/ C
           \/ Terminating

Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_vars

Termination == <>(pc = "Done")

\* END TRANSLATION
```

Here is the console output

```
Starting... (2021-09-03 18:07:58)
Computing initial states...
Finished computing initial states: 0 distinct states generated at 2021-09-03 18:08:03.
Model checking completed. No error has been found.
  Estimates of the probability that TLC did not check all reachable states
  because two distinct states had the same fingerprint:
  calculated (optimistic):  val = 0.0
Progress(1) at 2021-09-03 18:08:03: 0 states generated (0 s/min), 0 distinct states found (0 ds/min), 0 states left on queue.
0 states generated, 0 distinct states found, 0 states left on queue.
The depth of the complete state graph search is 1.
Finished in 6116ms at (2021-09-03 18:08:03)
```

Here is the model
[image]

I don't understand why it's choosing "No Behaviour Spec". The option list doesn't have anything else in it. The course however selects a "Temporal Formula". Where do I find that option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLC ignores everything below the `====` line. Move that after the "End Translation" line, and then in the model, under `What is the Behavior Spec`, set it to `Temporal Formula` and set the formula to `Spec`. Then it should work.